# brunch environment override files

Tags: javascript, environment, brunch

I would like to use different files based on which environment that I am using, very similar to

From what I read on [overrides](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md#overrides), I thought that I could specify a config like the following:

```
exports.config =
  files:
     javascripts:
        joinTo:
           'js/app.js': /Some_Pattern/i

  overrides:
     foo:
        files:
           javascripts:
              joinTo:
                 'js/app.js': /SOMEOTHER_Pattern/
```

But it seems that running
`brunch -env foo b` uses only the original pattern, and not the pattern specified from the overrides.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

seems like this is a bug in brunch. will fix in 1.7.6

Comment: Im using Branch 1.7.14 and this functionality is still not working ... or im doing something wrong.